# Controlling the empty dataset situation in while loop ( Oracle PLSQL )

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, while-loop, procedure

I've made this loop:

```
                LOOP -- arranging loop
                
                select  num_aula, tipo_aula -- dataset A
                into    na, ta
                from ( 
                        select num_aula,tipo_aula,abs(capienza-occ.score) -- dataset B 
                        from aula
                        join( 
                                select num_aula, tipo_aula -- dataset C
                                from aula
                                where tipo_aula = get_tipo_aula(occ.Nome_modulo,i)
                                minus
                                select num_aula, tipo_aula -- dataset D
                                from occr_lezione
                                where Nome_sede = occ.Nome_sede
                                and to_char(Data_fine_occr_lezione,'hh24mi') > to_char(occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24mi')
                                and to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24mi') < to_char(occ.Data_fine_occr_lezione,'hh24mi')
                                and to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'dd-mm-yyyy') = to_char(occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'dd-mm-yyyy')) 
                                using(num_aula,tipo_aula)
                                order by y, num_aula
                     ) where rownum=1;
                i := i+1;
                EXIT WHEN (na IS NOT NULL OR i > 2);
                END LOOP; -- arranging loop end
        i:=0;
```

In which the dataset B is a table obtained by the difference of the C and D selections, and the dataset A is the minimum value of it.

Now the dataset B can be empty, consequentially the dataset A have to be selected in an empty table, which of course result in an empty selection.

Since this is not acceptable in my code, I made a loop that should iterate every time this situation occur. To ease the times that this happens, I've bounded one of the inner parameters to a function, which give a different outcome based on the i counter.

The problem is that every time that the dataset B result empty the procedure in which this loop is coded stops giving me this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN.ASS_AULE", line 45
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How could I fix this? How can I force the procedure to not give up until the loop has ended?

So, this is the complete function, I've tried to add the exception handler at the bottom as you can see:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pprova
AS
CURSOR c1 is
select  occr_lezione.*, 
        Cont_iscr_occr_lezione( Codice_corso, 
                                Nome_modulo,
                                Data_inizio_ed_modulo, 
                                Giorno_lezione, 
                                Ora_inizio_lezione, 
                                Data_inizio_occr_lezione
                              ) score
from occr_lezione
where trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) >= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'lunedi'))
and   trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) <= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'venerdi'))
and   sem_check(sysdate,Data_inizio_ed_modulo) = 1
and  year_check(Data_inizio_ed_modulo,sysdate) = 1
order by score ;
occ c1%ROWTYPE;
na  NUMBER;
ta  VARCHAR2(20);
sc  NUMBER;
i   NUMBER;
BEGIN
i := 0;
--
OPEN c1;
LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO occ;
            EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;          
            IF occ.num_aula IS NULL AND occ.tipo_aula IS NULL
            THEN
                    LOOP -- arranging loop
                    -- dataset A
                    select  num_aula, tipo_aula
                    into    na, ta
                    from ( 
                            -- dataset B
                            select num_aula,tipo_aula,abs(capienza-occ.score) y
                            from aula
                            join(
                                    select num_aula, tipo_aula
                                    from aula
                                    where tipo_aula = get_tipo_aula(occ.Nome_modulo,i)
                                    minus
                                    select num_aula, tipo_aula
                                    from occr_lezione
                                    where Nome_sede = occ.Nome_sede
                                    and to_char(Data_fine_occr_lezione,'hh24mi') > to_char(occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24mi')
                                    and to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24mi') < to_char(occ.Data_fine_occr_lezione,'hh24mi')
                                    and to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'dd-mm-yyyy') = to_char(occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'dd-mm-yyyy')) 
                                    using(num_aula,tipo_aula)
                                    order by y, num_aula
                         ) where rownum=1;
                    EXIT WHEN (na IS NOT NULL OR i > 2);
                    END LOOP; -- arranging loop end
            i:=0;
            UPDATE  occr_lezione
                SET     Num_aula  = na,
                        Tipo_aula = ta
                WHERE   Codice_corso   = occ.Codice_corso
                AND     Nome_modulo    = occ.Nome_modulo
                AND     Giorno_lezione = occ.Giorno_lezione
                AND     Ora_inizio_lezione = occ.Ora_inizio_lezione
                AND     Data_inizio_occr_lezione = occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione;
            END IF;
END LOOP; -- fine loop di fetching
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found
THEN
IF i < 2
THEN NULL; -- Do nothing
ELSE RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20016,'non esistono combinazioni valide');
END IF;
END;
/
```

But as result each time the dataset spoken above is empty, it just skips the entire select - update part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am following your question, it sounds like you want to catch the `no_data_found` exception

```
LOOP
  BEGIN
    <<your SELECT INTO>>
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found
    THEN
      NULL; -- Do nothing
  END;

  i := i + 1;
  ...
END LOOP;
```

This assumes that you want to increment `i` when your `SELECT` statement returns no data.  If you want some of your logic to be executed only when the `SELECT` statement returns a row, you would put it between the `BEGIN` and the `EXCEPTION` keywords.

Not knowing the problem you are trying to solve, I'm always concerned when I see a `SELECT INTO` with a `rownum = 1` predicate.  If your query returns multiple rows, why do you want to pick an arbitrary row of data to populate your local variables?  I'm hard-pressed to think of many cases where that would make sense.  If you want to pick a specific row, code for that explicitly (i.e. use an appropriate `MAX` or `MIN` aggregate function, use an analytic function `rank` to rank the rows and pick one, etc.)

Comment: i will try to use a min in this case since i want to pick the row with a certain column that has the minimum value. The problem on the exception handling by the way is a little bit more complex since i want to do nothing only if the i counter is < 2, in other cases i should handle the error differently

Comment: @darkpirate - Obviously, feel free to add additional logic to your exception handler.  You can put whatever logic you'd like there so you can have an `IF` statement that looks at the value of `i`.

Comment: your code give me an error i think it's dued the position in wich i try to put the exception handler trough the code. Can i post the entire procedure at this point ?

Comment: @darkpirate - What error?  I did miss the `LOOP` in my `END LOOP`.  No idea if that's the error you're getting.

Comment: i assume that you can't position your handlers wherever you like in the code, right ?

Comment: @darkpirate - I don't understand the question.  You can always add an embedded PL/SQL block that contains an exception handler.  The `EXCEPTION` keyword must be paired with a `BEGIN` and an `END` that denote the scope of the embedded PL/SQL block.

Comment: my assumption was that it's possible to add only one begin - end  block of code.

Comment: @darkpirate - No.  You can have as many nested PL/SQL blocks as you'd like.  Well, there may be some limit to the number of levels you can nest but it's not one that a sane person would ever reach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73544/discussion-between-darkpirate-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 0):

Since i've posted the complete code, i will post the solution as well :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pprova
AS
CURSOR c1 is
select  occr_lezione.*, 
        Cont_iscr_occr_lezione( Codice_corso, 
                                Nome_modulo,
                                Data_inizio_ed_modulo, 
                                Giorno_lezione, 
                                Ora_inizio_lezione, 
                                Data_inizio_occr_lezione
                              ) score
from occr_lezione
where trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) >= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'lunedi'))
and   trunc(Data_inizio_occr_lezione) <= trunc(next_day(sysdate,'venerdi'))
and   sem_check(sysdate,Data_inizio_ed_modulo) = 1
and  year_check(Data_inizio_ed_modulo,sysdate) = 1
order by score ;
occ c1%ROWTYPE;
na  NUMBER;
ta  VARCHAR2(20);
sc  NUMBER;
i   NUMBER;
BEGIN
i := 0;
--
OPEN c1;
LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO occ;
            EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;          
            IF occ.num_aula IS NULL AND occ.tipo_aula IS NULL
            THEN
            BEGIN
                    LOOP -- arranging loop
                    -- dataset A
                    select  num_aula, tipo_aula
                    into    na, ta
                    from ( 
                            -- dataset B
                            select num_aula,tipo_aula,abs(capienza-occ.score) y
                            from aula
                            join(
                                    select num_aula, tipo_aula
                                    from aula
                                    where tipo_aula = get_tipo_aula(occ.Nome_modulo,i)
                                    minus
                                    select num_aula, tipo_aula
                                    from occr_lezione
                                    where Nome_sede = occ.Nome_sede
                                    and to_char(Data_fine_occr_lezione,'hh24mi') > to_char(occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24mi')
                                    and to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'hh24mi') < to_char(occ.Data_fine_occr_lezione,'hh24mi')
                                    and to_char(Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'dd-mm-yyyy') = to_char(occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione,'dd-mm-yyyy')) 
                                    using(num_aula,tipo_aula)
                                    order by y, num_aula
                         ) where rownum=1;
                    EXIT WHEN (na IS NOT NULL OR i > 2);
                    END LOOP; -- arranging loop end
                    EXCEPTION
                    WHEN no_data_found
                    THEN
                    IF i < 2
                    THEN NULL; -- Do nothing
                    ELSE RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20016,'non esistono combinazioni valide');
                    END IF;
                    i:=0;
                    END;
            UPDATE  occr_lezione
                SET     Num_aula  = na,
                        Tipo_aula = ta
                WHERE   Codice_corso   = occ.Codice_corso
                AND     Nome_modulo    = occ.Nome_modulo
                AND     Giorno_lezione = occ.Giorno_lezione
                AND     Ora_inizio_lezione = occ.Ora_inizio_lezione
                AND     Data_inizio_occr_lezione = occ.Data_inizio_occr_lezione;
            END IF;
END LOOP; -- fine loop di fetching
END;
/
```

As Justin pointed out, the exception scope is defined by the begin - end block of code it's in. This is very interesting, because it means that you can actually break your code in blocks and define for each different exception handlers. With this in mind i simply put my loop in a begin - end block and declared the handler within.